# ItemsControl with 2D Array and huge data amount

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, itemscontrol

i have a rather specific problem which i am trying to solve using WPF and C#.
When i try to present hierarchical 2D Data to my UI it works fine for small amount of data but starts lagging as crazy, when i try to render more data (above 100 x 100).

Code:

1. Source collection

```
// SilentObservableCollection has AddRange method which raises collection changed only once after all items are added
private SilentObservableCollection<List<MyViewModel>> data;
public SilentObservableCollection<List<MyViewModel>> Data
{
    get => this.data;
    private set => this.data = value;
}
```

2. Item in a collection (current state, more will follow)

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private SolidColorBrush color;
    public SolidColorBrush Color
    {
        get => this.color;
        set {
           this.color = value;
           this.OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Color));
        }
    }
   // Constructors, INotifyPropertyChanged implementation etc.
}
```

3. XAML Code

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Data}">
   <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
               <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                  <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
               </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                  <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1">
                     <Rectangle Width="30" Height="30" Fill="{Binding Path=Color}" />
                  </Border>
               </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         </ItemsControl>
      </DataTemplate>
   </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

What i have tried, but with no positive result:

1. Adding VirtualizingStackPanel to the outer ItemsControl
2. Wrapping outer ItemsControl in a ScrollViewer
3. Adding ScrollViewer to outer ItemsControl within ItemsControl.Template with ContentPresenter
4. Switching to ListView or ListBox (both loose interactivity i want for innermost Rectangles, need unnecessary styling to remove padding and borders, and still lag)

My general thoughts and questions:

1. I know that i am creating a whole new ItemsControl for each row, but i know of no other way to present 2D Data in proper hierarchy. Is there a better way?
2. I think that i somehow fail to render just the part which can be visible instead of all of the data at once, but i found no better solution.
3. I expect the data to be mostly below 1_000 X 1_000 and very rarely to go up to 5_000 x 5_000 and higher.
4. All my attempts to add proper scroll functionality have so far failed. Any suggestions?

Comment: This sounds like you need to render just the part that's visible. Odds are you're render attempts loaded more than necessary, and you need to force your program to not touch things outside of the desired area. Lmk if you need help diving deeper. I might be able to help you out privately more

Comment: You are creating a very inefficient layout. Both ItemControls don't use UI virtualization. Additionally, loading a single item results in instant loading of all the nested items. Its' not  clear what you exactly you are trying to achieve. But you must provide UI virtualization in order to make your view  efficient. Both ItemsControls must enable UI virtualization. Note that using a VirtualizingStackPanel is not enough. Both ItemControls must be scrollable i.e. they should not display all items instantly. The common way to display hierarchical data is to use the TreeView.

Comment: From a design perspective, you should not define brushes in your view model. Better expose Color objects. the advantage is that they are lightweight and don't have thread affinity (opposed to Brush). This is just a note. The main issue is that you show n² items at once.

Comment: TreeView would be more convenient as it allows the user to view all top level items. Imagine a list of your mentioned 5000*5000 items: the user would have to scroll 5001 items before he can view the second top level item. You definitely want a TreeView with collapsible nodes for this case.

Answer (score 0):

The layout, as described, does not virtualize the internal `ItemsControls`. Parent items measure their content with `double.PositiveInfinity` vertically, so the internal `ItemsControl` have all the space their need and the `VirtualizingStackPanel` never kicks in, but operates like a simple StackPanel. I would suggest that you should flatten the data source to a linear list and then resolve hierarchy in a purely visual way. [`ItemTemplateSelector`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplateselector?view=windowsdesktop-6.0) can come in handy:

```
<ItemsControl>
  <ItemsControl.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
      <ScrollViewer CanContentScroll="True">
        <ItemsPresenter />
      </ScrollViewer>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.Template>
  <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
      <VirtualizingStackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
    <local:HierarchicalTemplateSelector>
      <local:HierarchicalTemplateSelector.ChildTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </local:HierarchicalTemplateSelector.ChildTemplate>
      <local:HierarchicalTemplateSelector.ParentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" Margin="50 0 0 0"/>
        </DataTemplate>
      </local:HierarchicalTemplateSelector.ParentTemplate>
    </local:HierarchicalTemplateSelector>
  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplateSelector>
</ItemsControl>
```

And the selector itself:

```
public class HierarchicalTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public override DataTemplate SelectTemplate(object item, DependencyObject container)
    {
        return item is Child ? ChildTemplate : ParentTemplate;
    }

    public DataTemplate ChildTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate ParentTemplate { get; set; }
}
```

Hierarchy can be achieved by adding some indentation in the child template via margin or some alternative way.

Comment: *"The layout, as described, does not virtualize the internal ItemsControls."* - your layout doesn't utilize UI virtualization either. Also, you are basically reinventing a TreeView here.

Comment: There is still no UI virtualization enabled.

Comment: @BionicCode I guess you are referring to the lack of ItemsPanel in the definition. Just edited the post and added it. TreeView is better but it has quite a lot of features that might not be needed in this scenario.

Comment: No, adding a VirtualizingPanel alone is not sufficient. Also how do you display the nested items? The template selector will be applied to the top level items alone. Furthermore, there is no "location" in your visual tree to render any nested child items. Because TreeView offers features that you don't need  doesn't mean you should avoid it. It's a well tested and reliable control that at least knows how to display nested items. Your solution also doesn't solve the problem of showing n² items at once. I think unless the OP improves his answer to provide more details we can't solve his problem.

Comment: I understand what you are trying here (reinventing the TreeView). But you are far away to accomplish your goal.

Comment: I wanted to demonstrate just the basic idea for achieving this will a flat items controls and conditional templates. The TS won't be applied to the top level items alone, as I suggested that the OP should flatten the data source, if he/she want to go with this approach. Also he/she should add a scrollviewer in the template to enable scrolling as IC does not have one by default. I do not see any roadblocks to fully extend this approach if TV does not meet your needs. Also, why do you think that forcing IC to use VSP through ItemsPanel is not enough for UI virtualization?

Comment: You would also have to wrap the ItemsPresenter into a ScrollViewer which must have CanContentScroll set to True. Your current solution will display all items in a single line. In addition to this, you lack a ScrollViewer to prevent the control from stretching to show all items. It will make your items clip the screen with no chance to view them. You must also introduce a new data type Child in order to make you selector work.

Comment: Even if you finally make it work, a TreeView would be more convenient as it allows the user to view all top level items. Imagine a collection (as mentioned by the OP) of 5000*5000 items: the user would have to scroll 5001 items before he can view the second top level item. You definitely want a TreeView with collapsible nodes for this case. Instead of reinventing the TreeView, customize it if necessary.

Comment: Added the ScrollViewer in the template, as it is needed for the most basic scenario. Still, my point was to focus on the DataTemplateSector approach and not to provide a complete solution (as it is impossible with the scarce info that OP provided). Apparently, TV is more versatile, but also more visually-complex and packed with features that I do not know whether OP needs. It is up to OP to choose what to use when he/se knows the alternatives.